# Any Method Available That Will Execute Func<Foo> N Times And Get An IEnumerable<Foo>?

Tags: c#

I may only be asking this because I've blinded myself to something brilliantly obvious but,

I'm looking for something like this...

```
IEnumerable<Foo> fooSeq = Enumerable.Generate(()=> new Foo(), 5);
```

which would make fooSeq a sequence of 5 new Foo instances.

Can't seem to find it though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do but if you are trying to generate 5 Foo instances, this will work

```
IEnumerable<Foo> fooSeq = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new Foo())
```

Comment: is it cool to write sick code in 1 string? usual for loop to populate a List of items is clear and will be readable forever, not first 2 days after writing it. Also noone would be asking hmmm - why did he populate 5 Foos this sick way?

Comment: @Valentin I'm with you in everything you've said but IMHO, linq is very readable is very easy to get familiar with. To achieve the same result without linq, you WILL need a separate function doing something like `for(int i=0;i<5;i++) yield return new Foo();` (IEnumerable is not the same as List) and that might affect the readability so it's situational, debatable but mostly personal preference.

Comment: well you say you agree but you kind of dont at the same time. This code is not that easy even for people who are familiar with Linq, and author wasn't able to compose it himself. That should say enough already. And if you ask me Id say that it looks like a hack.  If you think List is not the same as inemurable you can cast it to IEnumerable, or use HashSet or some other collection that suits you for this need. Of course List is NOT IEnumerable because it inherits that interface but could you elaborate what exactly do you mean with that 'IEnumerable is not the same as List'?

Comment: I personnaly prefer `new object[5].Select(x => new Foo())` or `Enumerable.Repeat("", 5).Select(x => new Foo())`

Comment: @misterfrb but to use the `new object[5]` method you need to make an array... If we wanted a very large IEnumerable, you've got to waste the memory to create the array you're not using.