# Initialize multiple instances inline c#

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = Enumerable.Repeat(new Person(), 3).ToList<Person>();    
    }
}

class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dd");
    }
}
```

Output is a single line of "dd" instead of 3 lines, I don't understand

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6078552/340760

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

> Generates a sequence that contains **one** repeated value.

So it repeats the given value as many times as specified. It doesn't re-create the same value for each repetition. Hence in your example, only one `Person` instance is created and added to the list three times.

This is the equivalent of your code which might make it more clear:

```
var person = new Person();
List<Person> people = Enumerable.Repeat(person, 3).ToList<Person>();
```

If you want to create a different instance each time you can use `Select`:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(null, 3).Select(_ => new Person()).ToList();
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(_ => ...` would make more sense here.